# Pagination (mysql+php) on results dependent on drop-down menu filters

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, filter, pagination

I have this current query, and I am desperately trying to get the results paginated (total list - if no filters are applied by using the drop down menus is about 6000 rows), but don't know how. I've tried several tutorials already, but I keep getting my full list displayed, so the ceil() function never comes into play.
I think it is because my query isn't built to allow for a simple count on total rows in the query due to the pull down menus.

Can anyone help me build the pagination around this query?

```
$sql = "SELECT official_status, official_expiration_date, membership_status,membership_expiration_date, player_number, first_name, last_name, classification, gender, birth_year, rating, rating_effective_date, country, code, country.description, bracket.id, bracket.min, bracket.max, cutoff FROM Players, country, bracket, ratingscutoff WHERE membership_expiration_date >= cutoff AND Players.country = country.code ";

if (!empty($_GET['class'])) {
$filter_class = $_GET['class'];
$sql .= "AND classification = '{$filter_class}' ";
}
if (!empty($_GET['gender'])) {
$filter_gender = $_GET['gender'];
$sql .= "AND gender = '{$filter_gender}' ";
}
if (!empty($_GET['country'])) {
$filter_country = $_GET['country'];
$sql .= "AND country = '{$filter_country}' ";
}
if (empty($_GET['bracket'])) {
$filter_bracket = $_GET['bracket'];      
$sql .= "AND bracket.id = '0' AND Players.birth_year BETWEEN bracket.min AND bracket.max ";      
}        
else         
{
if (!empty($_GET['bracket'])) {
$filter_bracket = $_GET['bracket'];
$sql .= "AND bracket.id = '{$filter_bracket}' AND Players.birth_year BETWEEN bracket.min AND bracket.max ";
}
}
$sql .= "ORDER BY rating DESC, player_number ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("Unable to select: ".mysqli_error());
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$counter = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
printf("<tr>
<td class=\"stats\">$counter</td>
<td nowrap class=\"stats\"><b><a href=\"/player/%s\" target=\"_blank\">%s %s</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <img src=\"/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/%s.png\" title=\"certified official until %s\"/></b>
</td>
<td class=\"stats\"><span title=\"current member through %s\">%s</span></td>
<td class=\"stats\"><span title=\"rating updated %s\">%s</span></td>
<td class=\"stats\">%s</td>
<td class=\"stats\">%s</td>
<td class=\"stats\">%s</td>
\n",
$row["player_number"], $row["first_name"], $row["last_name"], $row["official_status"], $row["official_expiration_date"], $row["membership_expiration_date"], $row["player_number"], $row["rating_effective_date"], $row["rating"],  $row["classification"], $row["gender"], $row["description"]);
$counter++; //increment counter by 1 on every pass 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For pagination, in most cases you need 2 queries, a first that counts the total number of rows, and the second that actually returns the rowset using a LIMIT with the last offset and the number of rows per page.

Basically the 2 queries are the same, the first one being just a COUNT(). Run it, to get the total (I set it in a $num_rows variable in my example), then set a variable to have your number of rows per page (let's say $rows_per_page = 10;), and then before the scond query, do something like:

```
if (empty($_GET['page'])) {
        $page   = 1;
        $offset = $rows_per_page;
    } else {
        $num_pages = floor($num_rows / $rows_per_page);

        if ($_GET['page'] > $num_pages) {
            $page   = $num_pages;
        } else {
            $page   = $_GET['page'];
        }

        $offset = $rows_per_page * $page;
    }
```

You have your limits now for the second query:

```
LIMIT '.$offset.', '.$rows_per_page
```

**UPDATE**: I quickly wrote something using your code, it should work with minor changes (not tested)

```
$rows_per_page = 10;

$sql_count = "
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*)
    FROM 
        Players, country, bracket, ratingscutoff 
    WHERE membership_expiration_date >= cutoff 
    AND Players.country = country.code 
";
$result_count = mysqli_query($link, $sql_count) or die("Unable to select: ".mysqli_error());
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result_count);

if (empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $page   = 1;
    $offset = $rows_per_page;
} else {
    $num_pages = floor($num_rows / $rows_per_page);

    if ($_GET['page'] > $num_pages) {
        $page   = $num_pages;
    } else {
        $page   = $_GET['page'];
    }

    $offset = $rows_per_page * $page;
}

// Your other filters are being omitted for more clarity
$sql_select = "
    SELECT 
        official_status, official_expiration_date, membership_status,membership_expiration_date, player_number, first_name, last_name, classification, gender, birth_year, rating, rating_effective_date, country, code, country.description, bracket.id, bracket.min, bracket.max, cutoff
    FROM 
        Players, country, bracket, ratingscutoff 
    WHERE membership_expiration_date >= cutoff 
    AND Players.country = country.code 
    ORDER BY rating DESC, player_number ASC
    LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$rows_per_page."
";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql_select) or die("Unable to select: ".mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Hi Feub,
I only just discovered your reply.
Thank you. I will try this out soon.